# Django model group as a list

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with test data as below

id days

1, 30 
1, 40 
2, 10 
2, 20 
1, 90

I want output as

1, [30,40,90]
2, [10,20]

How can I get this in Django?

Comment: Seems like a `ManyToManyField` is what you should use instead of `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much Django, it's pure python. To get the result as a mapping on 'id' as key:

```
    result = {}
    for obj in Mymodel.objects.all():
        if result.has_key(obj.id):
            result[obj.id].append(obj.days)
        else:
            result[obj.id] = [obj.days]

    print result
    >>> {1: [30, 40, 90], 2: [10, 20]}
```

The order of the elements in each list is not defined. If you require these to be ordered, best would be to append `.order_by('days')` on the Queryset.

A final remark: Your 'id' is not unique. I would consider a non-pk-column named 'id' a bad practice, since 'id' is Django's default name for the automatically created pk-field.